# Open A Webpage Upon An Incoming Phone Call

Tags: ringcentral

I have a (hopefully) simple question about RingCentral capabilities.

Namely, is is possible to open a URL in a call center rep's browser upon an incoming phone call?

For instance, if **(555) 321-1234** calls, is it possible to open a web browser to the URL:

site.com/call?number=**5553211234**

If it *is* possible, what is the feature called (so I can look up tutorials)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In RingCentral, this sort of screen pop can be found in the "Execute Command" setting.

As a developer, I put the softphone into sandbox mode, hit the settings gear, go to "Calls" then edit the screen pop URL from there.